# internet Connection problem in ubuntu 12.04- pppoeconf

Tags: 12.04, internet-connection, pppoe, dsl

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my machine.  Previously, I had installed Ubuntu 11.04, which was connected to Internet (DSL) using the following command:

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

After completing the above in 11.04, I was able to connect to the Internet.  But in Ubuntu 12.04, I am not able to connect to Internet using that same command.  What do I need to do to connect to the Internet now?

Answer (score 1):

**Setting up a DSL connection in Ubuntu 12.04 with Network Manager**

1. Click the networking icon at the top right of the screen.
2. Click "Edit Connections..." from the drop-down menu.
3. Click on the "DSL" tab in the window that opens.
4. Click "Add"
5. Fill in as many details as were needed before.  If there is anything you don't know/you know is not needed, ignore it.

Comment: This uses Network manager, so I've slightly added to your answer to include that tool in the title of your instructions.

Comment: i have installed ubuntu 12.04 i am unable to connect to internet using PPPOeconf command.by adding DSL connection in network manager.